# How to return complex Json object in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using entity framework to get data from database and serialize it to JSON. And I want my JSON response looks like the one below.
Shoud I add `items` property to my model and make JSON I want? Thanks.

**Desired Json**

```
{
      "items" : [
        {
          "Id": 1,
          "AdContent":"Content1"
        },
        {
          "Id": 2,
          "AdContent":"Content2"
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "AdContent":"Content3"
        }   
      ]
}
```

**Current JSON I receive**

```
[
    {
        "Id":1,
        "AdContent":"Content1"
    },
    {
         "Id":2,
         "AdContent":"Content2"
    },
    { 
         "Id":3,
         "AdContent":"Content3"
    }
]

{
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetJson()
{
     using (var db = new DoskaUsContext())
     {
         List<AdViewModel> list = db.Ads.Select(x => new AdViewModel
         {
             Id = x.AdId,                    
             AdContent = x.AdContent
         }).ToList();

         return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
}
```

**Model**

```
 public class AdViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AdContent { get; set; }        
    }
```

Comment: `return Json(new { items = list }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous object is one solution `Json(new {items=list},...)`.

General approach to solve that problem - generate strongly typed classes with http://json2csharp.com/ and populate result via generated classes or at least see what is missing from your code.

In this particular case generated code:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AdContent { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

Which shows missing piece of the puzzle - `RootObject` with list property `items`.

Answer (score 1):

Create another model which hold collection of `AdViewModel` as items

```
 public class AdViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AdContent { get; set; }        
    }

 public class NewModel
    {
        public AdViewModel items { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Okay i create with as you say, but what next?I have same problem?